# system image size increased after removing packages

Tags: remastersys

i remastered my system. the output image was of 2.5 gb. so i removed packages about 1gb & then remastered system but now final image is of more than 4 gb. I also tried relinux but it also produces same results. I am using ubuntu 12.04 & want to create installation image similar to default one.

Comment: How are you generating the image?

Comment: I am using "remastersys" & "relinux" software for generating image. There is option in remastersys to create live cd similar to original Ubuntu image.

Comment: Try removing /home/remastersys or /home/relinux before running it again. And if you're using relinux, I recommend using relinux 0.3a3 or later (preferably 0.4), as it might help fix that issue too.